# Why won't my swift collection view show anything

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I want to make a simple collection view just showing some pictures but the cells wont show

```swift
import UIKit

final class HomePageViewController: UICollectionViewController {
    // MARK: - Properties

    
    override func loadView() {
        super.loadView()
        
        let collectionView = UICollectionView(frame: .zero, collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewFlowLayout())
        collectionView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.view.addSubview(collectionView)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            collectionView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor),
            collectionView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.bottomAnchor),
            collectionView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.leadingAnchor),
            collectionView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.trailingAnchor),
            ])
        self.collectionView = collectionView
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        self.collectionView.backgroundColor = .white
        self.collectionView.dataSource = self
        self.collectionView.delegate = self

        
        self.collectionView.register(HomePageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "HomePageCell")
    }

    
    
    // MARK: - Private


    
    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "HomePageCell", for: indexPath) as! HomePageCell
            cell.Picture.image = UIImage(named: "songpic-1")
        
        return cell
    }

}

extension HomePageViewController: UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        
        return CGSize(width: collectionView.bounds.size.width - 16, height: 200)
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        minimumLineSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 8
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        minimumInteritemSpacingForSectionAt section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 0
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView,
                        layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout,
                        insetForSectionAt section: Int) -> UIEdgeInsets {
        return UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 8, left: 8, bottom: 8, right: 8)
    }
}
```

```
import UIKit



class HomePageCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    
    @IBOutlet weak var Picture: UIImageView!
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        let Picture = UIImageView(frame: .zero)
        Picture.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.contentView.addSubview(Picture)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            Picture.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.topAnchor),
            Picture.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.bottomAnchor),
            Picture.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.leadingAnchor),
            Picture.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.contentView.trailingAnchor),
            ])
        
        
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = .lightGray
        
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        
        fatalError("Interface Builder is not supported!")
    }
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }
    
    override func prepareForReuse() {
        super.prepareForReuse()
    
    }
    
        
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can delete/comment your `loadView()` implementation and things should work just fine. You will still get a `UICollectionView` to work with.

The `loadView()` implementation is supposed to provide a `UIView` instance that's to be assigned to `UIViewController.view` property. In your implementation however, we are using it via `self.view` directly without assigning it first.

From [`UIViewController.loadView()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621454-loadview) docs -

> You can override this method in order to create your views manually. **If you choose to do so, assign the root view of your view hierarchy to the `view` property.** The views you create should be unique instances and should not be shared with any other view controller object. **Your custom implementation of this method should not call super.**

---

##### What to do if this still doesn't show up?

Check using `View Hierarchy Debugger` that at run time your `collectionView` has non-zero `width` & `height` values. If any of the `width` OR `height` is zero, you will run into this issue.